# How to debug SMTP authentication errors with JavaMail?

Tags: authentication, smtp, jakarta-mail

Below is the code that I'm using:

```
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        // props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", server);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
        Transport transport = null;
        try {
            transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            session.setDebug(true);
            transport.connect(server, username, password);
        } catch(AuthenticationFailedException message){
            System.out.println("Authentication Failed... terminating!");
            System.out.println(message);
            System.exit(16);
        }
```

Unfortunately, I don't get to see the session handshake. Do I have the setDebug in the wrong place?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to set it before the Transport object is created.  Move it up one line.

Note also that starting with JavaMail 1.4.5 the details of the authentication exchange are not displayed by default.  You'll need to set "mail.debug.auth" to "true" to see that.